# nusoap client not not responding

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I'm trying to write a simple web service server and client using nusoap.  I think my server works fine because a VB.NET client can call it.  However, the PHP client has a very long loading time and does not give any output.

server1.php

```
<?
require_once("nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");

$ns="localhost/";

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('TaxCalculator', $ns);
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns;
$server->register('TaxCalc', array('amount'=>'xsd:string'),array('return'=>'xsd:string'),$ns);

function TaxCalc($amount) {
  $tax = $amount * 0.5;
  return new soapval('return', 'xsd:string', $tax);
}

$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

client1.php

```
<? 
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$client=new soapclient('http://localhost/server1.php?wsdl', 'wsdl');
echo $client->call('TaxCalc', array('amount'=>'15.00'));
?>
```

I'm using PHP Version 5.2.6 and nusoap version 0.9.5.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use whatever works.

I have used nusoap.php,v 1.114 and it works for me.

The nuspoap_client call I have is different from what you have above. Yours does not have a paramter for what port to use.

```
$client = new nusoap_client("http://127.0.0.1:1024/soap/IApp", false,
$proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);
```

The 2nd parameter above says not to use a wsdl file.
I am guessing that maybe your VB client uses the same approach.

Your code looks like it wants to use a local wsdl file.

Alternatively maybe there is a permissions issue where VB is allowed to access the soap port and PHP is not. (doubt it as everything is local)